# Javascript: Globalizing variables inside function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, globalization

So I have the following code:

```
var func1 = function() {
    var userChoose = prompt("Choose a number from 1-10. If you choose the same number as the computer, you win!");
    func2();
};

var func2 = function() {
    computerChoose = Math.random();
    computerChoose = Math.round(computerChoose*10)/10;
    if (userChoose === computerChoose) {
        console.log("You won! The computer chose the number " + userChoice + " just like you! Good job!");
    } else if (userChoose > 10) {
        console.log("I'm sorry, you wrote something above 10. Try again.");
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry! The computer got " + computerChoose + 
        " and you got " + userChoose + ". Sorry!");
    }
};

func1();
```

The problem I have is that once I place a number, say 5, it will stay with that number and every time I run the code it will say "Sorry! The computer got x and you got 5.", even if I put 3.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this happens because i'm trying to change a variable that is inside a function. My main question is how do I globalize a variable that is inside a function, so it can be used and modified in different functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the values when you call the function. Try this:

```
var func1 = function() {
    var userChoose = prompt("Choose a number from 1-10. If you choose the same number as the computer, you win!");
    func2(userChoose);
};

var func2 = function(userChoose ) {
    computerChoose = Math.random();
    computerChoose = Math.round(computerChoose*10)/10;
    if (userChoose === computerChoose) {
        console.log("You won! The computer chose the number " + userChoice + " just like you! Good job!");
    } else if (userChoose > 10) {
        console.log("I'm sorry, you wrote something above 10. Try again.");
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry! The computer got " + computerChoose + 
        " and you got " + userChoose + ". Sorry!");
    }
};

func1();
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h5R9L/)